# Contador e calculo em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso pegar um valor e dividir pela quantidade digitada no input

```
<h2 class="m-b-0 text-white font-weight-normal" id="valortotal">R$ 4.000,00</h2></div>
```

Pegar esse valor e dividir pela quantidade digitado aqui:

```
<div style="border-color: #333 !important;" class="qty mt-6">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="text" class="count" name="qty" value="1"> 
    <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
```

E mostrar o resultado:

```
<div  class="col-6">
    <h5 class="card-subtitle">Individual</h5>
    <h3 class="font-weight-bold">R$ 4.000,00</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `id` nos elementos por serem de identificação únicos
- input type="number" min="1"
- forma dinamica: função onchange
- toLocaleString('pt-BR') - converte Numero para String currency nativo. Detalhe, legal, está seguro contra o bug do ponto flutuante

```js
    // Resultado bugado
    console.log(0.1+0.2);
    // Resultado sem bugs
    console.log((0.1+0.2).toLocaleString());
```

**Código**

```js
//função para converter o valor em um numero que se possa utilizar em operações aritméticas.
function converteMoedaFloat(valor){
          
     if(valor === ""){
          valor =  0;
      }else{
          valor = valor.replace("R$ ","");
          valor = valor.replace(".","");
          valor = valor.replace(",",".");
          valor = parseFloat(valor);
       }
       return valor;
}

function calcular(){
    var valortotal=document.getElementById('valortotal').innerHTML;

    var valorConvertido = (converteMoedaFloat(valortotal));

    var qty=document.getElementById('qty').value;

    var result =(valorConvertido/qty);

    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML= (result.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }));

}
```

```html
    <h2 class="m-b-0 text-white font-weight-normal" id="valortotal">R$ 4.000,80</h2></div>


    <div style="border-color: #333 !important;" class="qty mt-6">
        
        <input type="number" class="count" id="qty" name="qty" value="1" min="1" onchange="calcular()"> 
       
    </div>


    <div  class="col-6">
        <h5 class="card-subtitle">Individual</h5>
        <h3 class="font-weight-bold" id="resultado">R$ 4.000,80</h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser apenas logar o valor e mudar a quantidade a ser dividida pelo valor, pode fazer desta maneira:

```js
let valortotal = 4000;

    let calc = valortotal / document.getElementById('qtde').value;
    console.log('R$'+calc);
```

```html
<h2 class="m-b-0 text-white font-weight-normal">R$ 4.000,00</h2></div>

<div style="border-color: #333 !important;" class="qty mt-6">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="text" class="count" name="qty" id="qtde" value="4">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>

<div  class="col-6">
    <h5 class="card-subtitle">Individual</h5>
    <h3 class="font-weight-bold">R$ 4.000,00</h3>
</div>
```

Agora, se quiser fazer de uma forma mais dinâmica, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
let valortotal = 4000;

    document.querySelector('#qtde').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        let key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (key === 13) {
            let calc = valortotal / document.querySelector('#qtde').value;
            //console.log('R$'+calc);

            document.getElementById('resposta').innerHTML = `R$`+calc;

        }
    });
```

```html
<h2 class="m-b-0 text-white font-weight-normal">R$ 4.000,00</h2></div>

<div style="border-color: #333 !important;" class="qty mt-6">
    <span class="minus">-</span>
    <input type="text" class="count" name="qty" id="qtde">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>

<div  class="col-6">
    <h5 class="card-subtitle">Individual</h5>
    <h3 class="font-weight-bold">R$ 4.000,00</h3>

</div>

<div id="resposta">
  <!--A resposta da divisão ficará aqui-->
</div>
```

Quando digitar o valor que deseja dividir os 4000 e pressionar enter, o valor aparecerá na div com id "resposta", futuramente poderá colocar a ação do enter em um botão para o layout ficar mais bonito, porem acredito que tirei suas duvidas

Espero ter ajudado ^^

Comment: Otima ajuda, parabéns